# Why can't my DJS bot find my commands folder?

Tags: node.js, discord.js, fs, enoent

I'm making a command handler for my discord.js bot. But the bot cannot find the "commands" folder.

Line code I have problems with:

```
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
```

[image: Folders]

Error message :

> Uncaught Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir './commands'

What is the problem and what is the solution?

Comment: Where is the file you import the `./commands` dir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wrapping the ./commands with grave accents:

```
`./commands`
```

instead of './commands' or append a "/" to the end, helps sometimes.

If you want the handler to recursively search for all your commandfiles, e.g. you created subdirectories to organize your commands, you can use the function I use (and recommend):

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const rootDir = path.dirname(require.main.filename);
const fileArray = [];

const readCommands = (dir) => {

    const __dirname = rootDir;

    // Read out all command files
    const files = fs.readdirSync(path.join(__dirname, dir));

    // Loop through all the files in ./commands
    for (const file of files) {
        // Get the status of 'file' (is it a file or directory?)
        const stat = fs.lstatSync(path.join(__dirname, dir, file));

        // If the 'file' is a directory, call the 'readCommands' function
        // again with the path of the subdirectory
        if (stat.isDirectory()) {
            readCommands(path.join(dir, file));
        }
        else {
            const fileDir = dir.replace('\\', '/');
            fileArray.push(fileDir + '/' + file);
        }
    }
};


readCommands('commands');
```